# Converting IF statements to simple statement - Which one is efficient?

Tags: c#

I hope everyone will enjoy reading this.

I have two IF statements below

```
public int GetTax(Item item)
{
   int tax=0;
   if(item.Name.Equals("Book"))
   {
      tax = 10;
   }
   if(item.Imported)
   {
      tax += 5;
   }
   return tax;
}
```

I have converted above if condition to this.

```
public int GetTax(Item item)
{
     return 5 * ((int)item.Name.Equals("Book") * 2 + ((int)item.Imported));
}
```

Which one do you think efficient? and justify why?

Comment: "I hope everyone will enjoy reading this" - I didn't.

Comment: In the above case, I don't see a performance issue. But obfuscating your intent like that is bad. Make readable code, unless it *really* needs optimization like above. In that case, document it thoroughly.

Comment: are you sure both will give the same output?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "efficient"?

Comment: The two blocks of code don't perform the same operations. Anyway, this is not a constructive question involving facts and is very likely to solicit discussion ("this is better because of this and that...", "i disagree..."), and will probably be closed soon. This said, your answer is: it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks ronalchn and good spot. Efficient in the sense, i heard few developers told that a application should use very less if/case conditions. So, i just tricked to avoid 'if' condition but would like to know your suggestion / ideas.

Comment: those downvoters, before doing it please put a comment why are you down voting? I posted this question to get an idea or perspective of yours and not down voting.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that your second code block won't compile (you can't convert .Equals() result which is bool to int, and I assume .Imported is a bool property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If compiled literally the 2nd method is more efficient, because there is no branching.

Whenever there is branching, there is some branch prediction, which could miss, and therefore cause the CPU to re-execute the machine instructions.

Having said that, depending on the compiler, what you have written may be simple enough for it to optimize to equivalent code. This does depend on the return type of what you call. If the return type is boolean, they are equivalent.

However, if for example, `item.Imported` is actually of integer type, then the two examples you gave are not equivalent, and the compiler may not compile both to the same thing.

Because optimization is very compiler-dependent. If it was important to minimize runtime, you will only know for sure if you **benchmark** the code.